# Python wrapper for Yahoo Content Analysis API

Tags: python, nlp, yahoo-api

I am working on writing a keyword extractor in Python.  I would like to use the Yahoo Content API.  The question is, is there a Python2.7 (or even 3.x) wrapper for the Yahoo Content API?  I could not find one doing normal searches.

In parallel, I am trying alchemyAPI, OpenCalais, DBPedia Spotlight.  I would love to make a comparison to figure out which one to use in production.

Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to spin off your second query into its own question. It'll help both it and your main question

Comment: I mean the comparison of those products along with Yahoo.  If you feel that's still confusing, happy to split it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was interested in the answer as well. This is a possible solution:

```
import requests

text = """
Italian sculptors and painters of the renaissance favored the Virgin Mary for inspiration
"""

payload = {'q': "select * from contentanalysis.analyze where text='{text}'".format(text=text)}
r = requests.post("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql", data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/content/V2/contentAnalysis.html), you can POST requests to the Yahoo content API and get JSON back. Python has the [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html), [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) libraries for that, all of which are well-documented and easy to use.